# Powershell Invoke-Expression mangling command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to invoke a command from a powershell script. The command works fine when run from a normal command line. Here is the full command (sorry, it's long, but if I truncate it I'm afraid I might leave out something significant.)

```
C:\Users\Dave.Work\Desktop\wix36-binaries\candle.exe C:\Users\Dave.Work\Developer\MapCreator\install\win\product.wxs -arch x64 -dPlatform=x64 -dProductVersion=0.9.1.0 -dKarteReleaseBinDir=C:\Users\Dave.Work\Developer\MapCreator\karte-build-release\release -out C:\Users\Dave.Work\Developer\MapCreator\install\win\obj\
```

If I invoke this *exact same command* using `Invoke-Expression`, it fails. It gives an error from the executable (`candle.exe`), but since it works fine from the command line, the problem is clearly that powershell is mangling the string somehow. Here is my call:

```
Invoke-Expression 'C:\Users\Dave.Work\Desktop\wix36-binaries\candle.exe C:\Users\Dave.Work\Developer\MapCreator\install\win\product.wxs -arch x64 -dPlatform=x64 -dProductVersion=0.9.1.0 -dKarteReleaseBinDir=C:\Users\Dave.Work\Developer\MapCreator\karte-build-release\release -out C:\Users\Dave.Work\Developer\MapCreator\install\win\obj\'
```

This results in the following error from `candle.exe`:

```
candle.exe : error CNDL0103 : The system cannot find the file '.9.1.0' with type 'Source'.
```

Somehow the numeric version number is getting mangled? Again, it works fine from a command line.

*How to I pass this command to Powershell?*

**[NOTE]** Ultimately, this command is generated from variables, i.e. the actual command will be something like:

```
$WixDir\candle.exe $ScriptDir\product.wxs -arch $Platform -dPlatform=$Platform -dProductVersion=$ProductVersion -dKarteReleaseBinDir=$KarteReleaseBinDir -out $ScriptDir\obj\
```

I'm using `Invoke-Expression` because I was having major problems expanding the variables using, for example, the call operator. But I can't get it to work even without the variable expansion. Thus, if the solution is to escape certain parts of the command string, I would need to also know how to apply those escapes to variables.

Comment: First of all try this "-dProductVersion=0.9.1.0" enclosed with ".

Comment: @RomanKuzmin: Yes, that does it. And it looks like the variable-enabled version (using double quotes) is `" ... -dPlatform=$Platform ""-dProductVersion=$ProductVersion"" -dKarteReleaseBinDir= ... "` If you want to put that in an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. I'd also be curious as to *why* that works. I thought single quotes were supposed to preserve the string.

Comment: Or with '. My `get-arg` tool shows that the original command is split: `-dProductVersion=0` and `.9.1.0` are different arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try "-dProductVersion=0.9.1.0" enclosed with " or with '. My `Get-Arg` utility shows that the original command is parsed so that `-dProductVersion=0` and `.9.1.0` are different arguments.

Just in case, my Get-Arg.exe is (C#):

```
using System;
class GetArg
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach(string s in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

It is useful for checking such cases.

---

There is even simpler illustration. This code

```
function Get-Argument {
    $args
}

Get-Argument -dProductVersion=0.9.1.0
```

gets this output:

```
-dProductVersion=0
.9.1.0
```

That is PowerShell treats such a command as having two arguments.

---

### Explanation

In [PowerShell 2 0 Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9706) we can see for parameters

```
parameter-char:
Any Unicode character except
{   }   (   )   ;   ,   |   &   .   [
colon
whitespace
new-line-character
```

Note: '=' is included, '.' is excluded. In our case we have

```
-dProductVersion=0.9.1.0
```

According to the specification all characters before '.' are valid parameter
characters. So we get, the first result argument is `-dProductVersion=0`

Then parser chokes at '.'. Technically, it looks like we do something against
the rules including '.' into the argument that starts with '-'. That is why we
should enclose the whole argument with ' or ".

This is probably true for the other excluded characters as well.